# Filter an object iside an array

Tags: javascript

I need to delete entire object that do not have passed

here is the array

```js
const array = [{
    course: 1,
    list: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "john",
        code: true
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "maria",
        code: true
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    course: 2,
    list: [{
        id: 3,
        name: "rose"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "mark",
        code: true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

That i need is remove obj that not have code:true, and get this

```js
const array = [{
    course: 1,
    list: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "john",
      code: true
    }, ]
  },
  {
    course: 2,
    list: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "mark",
      code: true
    }]
  }
]
```

I tried to make a map inside a filter, but it does not work at all

```js
const remove = array.filter(function(lines) {
  return lines.map(line => line.list.map(list => list.code))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map through the array, then copy all properties of the specific item and separately do the filtering on the list attribute.

```js
const array = [{
    course: 1,
    list: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "john",
        code: true
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "maria",
        code: true
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    course: 2,
    list: [{
        id: 3,
        name: "rose"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "mark",
        code: true
      }
    ]
  }
]

const filter = arr => arr.map(arrItem => ({ 
     ...arrItem,
    list: arrItem.list.filter( listItem => listItem.code )
  })
)

console.log( filter(array) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const filtered = [];

arr.forEach(item => {
  const list = item.list.filter(listItem => listItem.code);

  if(list.length > 0) {
     filter.push({ ...item, list });
  }
});
```

This approach will only add items to the filtered output array if the list contains any items after filtering out those with `code: false`. To include them anyway, you could do:

```
const filtered = arr.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  list: item.list.filter(listItem => listItem.code)
});
```